# How can I block visitors from a specific country with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any way of blocking my site to visitors that come from certain countries using the htaccess file? If possible, how should the line(s) of code look like?

Comment: http://www.countryipblocks.net/country-blocks/htaccess-deny-format/ Won't help with proxy servers, though.

Comment: Many thanks Cody. I am aware that via a proxy won't work, but at least it is something. Many thanks